# Check space in a string in two loops

Tags: c++

In the proccess of creating a user register, I see a double do {} while loop with **a same condition.** The condition is if detected a space in the strings, the reading will not become available.

```
void createAccount() 
{
    unsigned short int i = 0;
    bool space = false;

    cin.ignore();

    cout << "FIRST NAME: ";
    getline(cin, fullName[0]);

    do {
        cout << "MIDDLE NAME: ";
        getline(cin, fullName[1]);

        for (i = 0; i < fullName[1].size(); i++) 
        {
            if (fullName[i][1] == 32) {
                space = true;
                break;
            }

            else {
                space = false;
                break;
            }
        }   
    } while(space);

    /*Reset values for the same loop again (I would not like to write 2 times all of this)
    i is reseted at loop-for, which helps.*/
    space = false;

    do {
        cout << "MIDDLE NAME: ";
        getline(cin, fullName[1]);

        for (i = 0; i < fullName[1].size(); i++) 
        {
            if (fullName[i][1] == 32) {
                space = true;
                break;
            }

            else {
                space = false;
                break;
            }
        }   
    } while(space);

    fullName[3] = fullName[0] + string(" ") + fullName[1] + string(" ") + fullName[2];
}
```

I really don't know how can I put this together in a same loop. I'm mind broken.

**@edit:** I'm roger that the right thing is to put fullName[1][i] and that the breaks conditions are wrong.

**@edit²:** The result:

```
class BankAccount 
{
private:    
    string fullName[5];
    char accountAddress[10];
    unsigned short int cards;
    float money;
    bool visa, mastercard, americanExpress;

    void checkName(string name, string typeName, bool exception)
    {
        unsigned short int errorVar, i;
        errorVar = i = 0;
        bool space = false;

        do {
            if (errorVar > 0)
                cout << "Enter only the name purposed." << endl << endl;    

            if (exception)
                cout << typeName << " NAME (type no if you haven't): ";

            else
                cout << typeName << " NAME: ";

            getline(cin, name);

            for (i = 0; i < name.size(); i++)
            {
                if (name[i] == ' ')
                {
                    space = true;
                    break;
                }

                else
                    space = false;
            }

            errorVar++;
        } while (space);

        if (name.compare("no") == 0)
            name = "NULL";
    }

public:
    void createAccount() 
    {   
        cout << endl << "FIRST NAME: "; /* First name has no checks (it can be a compound name) */         
        getline(cin, this->fullName[0]); 

        checkName(this->fullName[1], "SECOND", false);
        checkName(this->fullName[2], "THIRD", true); 
        checkName(this->fullName[3], "LAST", false);

        if (this->fullName[2].compare("NULL") == 0)
        {
            this->fullName[4] = this->fullName[0] + string(" ") + this->fullName[1] + string(" ") + this->fullName[3];  //NOT FULL NAME
            cout << this->fullName[4];
        }

        else
        {
            this->fullName[4] = this->fullName[0] + string(" ") + this->fullName[1] + string(" ") + this->fullName[2] + string(" ") + this->fullName[3];  //NOT FULL NAME
            cout << this->fullName[4]; 

        }
    }

    BankAccount() {/* Constructor */}
    ~BankAccount() {/* Deconstructor */}
};
```

Logically it's a simple stuff. Thanks for helping and improve the code also in other areas.

Comment: Why don't you create a function?

Comment: Why write a loop if you will always break?

Comment: As a side note: Don't use magic numbers, better use `if (fullName[i][1] == ' ') {`.

Comment: If detected a space in the string already, there's no need to keep checking the others slots. That's why the break.

Comment: Not to mention I don't think you want `fullname[i][1]`, wouldn't it be `fullname[1][i]`?

Comment: `if break; else break;` sounds a lot like you are always breaking, regardless of the condition

Comment: True zz, gonna fix that later, but the main point still put it together in a same loop.

Comment: You could simplify this by calling [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious and clean solution is to put the do-loop in a function (or method), and call it twice, once with `fullname[1]` and then again with `fullname[2]`.

Comment: how da f I didnt think about that